# How do I populate a listbox in MFC with data from an XML file?

Tags: c++, xml, mfc, listbox

I was just wondering if it was possible to populate a listbox with data from an a xml file? If anyone could help me out here I would be extremeley grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`AddString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cekde96.aspx) member function to add an item to the `CListBox`.

For parsing the XML there are a lot of different parsers to use. [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/), [RapidXml](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/), for instance.